# İ need some directories and files must be a hidden, for example /.htaccess/

Tags: http, web

İ need directories and files in the web web servers. Examples; can you write dir or file must be hidden

```
/admin.php/
/.htaccess/
/wp-config.php/
```

Comment: This question is really unclear, and I for one have no idea how to try and help you. Some context about what you are trying to do would be helpful

Comment: i need just possible hidden directories

Comment: Ah, wait: are you talking about hidden files in *Nix sense (i.e. .htaccess, .bashrc, .profile, .config), or are you concerned about preventing access to wp-config.php and admin.php via your webserver? Is there something specific you are trying to achieve (e.g. securing wordpress), or are you doing some kind of inventory?

Comment: What do you mean with "hidden"?

Comment: @MücahitDemirhan Do you want to know *how* to hide files and directories? How to *find* hidden files and directories? Do you want a list of typical hidden files and directories? Your wording of the question is missing some critical words to make it clear.

Comment: Yeh i need important files for security

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find`.

If you need all the files in your current directory: `find .`

If you need the hidden files in your current directory: `find . -iname ".*"`

If you need only hidden directories: `find . -iname ".*" -type d`

If you need only hidden files: `find . -iname ".*" -type f`